# Changing update value from true to false in Python

Tags: python

Creating a sql table in python and want it to drop and re-create the table the first time I run the script then after that I want to set the update(new=False). Maybe I'm over looking something simple. What I have now is:

```
for dt in date_range.iterdateranges(7):
    date = dt.sql
    orders.substitutions['date'] = date
    x=True
    update =orders.update(new=x)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you move `x` out of the loop you can set it after use and get what you're looking for. This way it'll be true once and then false every other time

```
x = True
for dt in date_range.iterdateranges(7):
    date = dt.sql
    orders.substitutions['date'] = date    
    update =orders.update(new=x) 
    x=False
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to learn python on the fly for work and I tend to put things in the wrong spot often so far.